# String manipulation based on dictionary

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` used to match a `string` to a new one.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "foo", "bar" }
};
```

The method I use to match the `string`:

```
public static string GetValueOrKeyAsDefault(this Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, string key)
{
    string value;
    return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : key;
}
```

Used like so:

```
string s1 = dictionary.GetValueOrKeyAsDefault("foo"); /* s1 equals "bar" */
string s2 = dictionary.GetValueOrKeyAsDefault("test"); /* s2 equals "test" */
```

I now want to match a `string` partially and keep part of this string in the matched one.

```
/* {0} is arbitrary, could be anything else */
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "SPROC:{0}", "{0}" },
    { "onClick='{0}(this)'", "{0}" }
};

string s1 = dictionary.SomeMethod("SPROC:my_sproc"); /* s1 equals "my_sproc" */
string s2 = dictionary.SomeMethod("onClick='HandleOnClick(this)'"); /* s1 equals "HandleOnClick" */
```

I feel like `regex` could be a way but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: How does your SomeMethod know which part of the string to match? What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If `{0}` is arbitrary, what is the rule for a match here? If the value/key ends with the key/value? Or just one contains another? And if several meet the requirement?

Comment: @user3387223 The result I'm trying to achieve is to get a part of the `string`. The match should be *dynamic*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The symbol `{0}` is arbitrary, I could have used `XXX`. The idea would still be to isolate `XXX` and build a new string with it.

Comment: But why does the final string `my_sproc` not contain the value of the dictionary which is `{0}`? I thought that it was the replacement.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `{0}` is just a symbol to know which part of the string I want to keep. That's why it is *dynamic* as I don't know its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that using a `Dictionary<,>` here is "morally" wrong... I would use a `List<Tuple<Regex, string>>`. It is morally wrong for two reasons: the ordering (so the priority) of the various key-values isn't "fixed" and could be quite random AND you can't leverage on the strength of the `Dictionary<,>`: the O(1) exact match (`TryGetValue`).

Still:

```
public static string SomeMethod(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, string str)
{
    foreach (var kv in dictionary)
    {
        var rx = new Regex(kv.Key);

        if (rx.IsMatch(str))
        {
            string replaced = rx.Replace(str, kv.Value);
            return replaced;
        }
    }

    return str;
}

Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { @"SPROC:(.*)", "$1" },
    { @"onClick='(.*)\(this\)'", "$1" }    
};

string replaced = SomeMethod(dictionary, "SPROC:my_sproc");
```

Note that you have to use the `Regex` "language" (see the `(.*)` and the `$1`)

Without the useless `Dictionary<,>`:

```
public static string SomeMethod(IEnumerable<Tuple<Regex, string>> tuples, string str)
{
    foreach (var rr in tuples)
    {
        if (rr.Item1.IsMatch(str))
        {
            string replaced = rr.Item1.Replace(str, rr.Item2);
            return replaced;
        }
    }

    return str;
}

var dictionary = new[] 
{
    Tuple.Create(new Regex("SPROC:(.*)"), "$1"),
    Tuple.Create(new Regex(@"onClick='(.*)\(this\)'"), "$1"),
};

string replaced = SomeMethod(dictionary, "SPROC:my_sproc");
```

As a sidenote, I would add a `^` at the beginning of each regex and a `$` at the end of each regex, like `"^SPROC:(.*)$"`, just to be sure that the regex won't match partial substrings.

Comment: Thank you, you really understood what I wanted to do. You nailed it!